# What is the lifetime of an azure Service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-service-principal

I am planning to use a service principal for automated login to azure through powershell but I could not find any documentation covering its lifetime or for how long the credentials will be valid ?
If it has limited lifetime, can we extend it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the expiration time (in months) for a service principal credentials (3, 12, 18, 24 or custom).

Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> All applications.

Existing Service Principal:

Select the service principal. The Client credentials link will show you the expiration date for each of the Client secrets.

Create a Service Principal:

Click New registration. Create the service principal. Then create a new Client credentials and set the expiration timeframe.

Comment: Thank you so much!! what would be the appropriate way of specifying that I don't want it to ever expire? I was creating it through powershell and there is an EndDate parameter, would that be the best way to set an infinite lifetime?

Comment: @korra - The maximum end value is 24 months after the start value. An infinite lifetime is not supported.

Comment: but when i gave the end date a 1000 years from now (through EndDate parameter in powershell for New-AzADServicePrincipal cmdlet ) , the SP was successfully created without any warning/errors regarding the end date

Comment: Check in the Azure Portal GUI for the actual expiration date.